# How to solve error Image source not readable

Tags: php, laravel-5

previously i got error MissingDependencyException in ImageManager.php line 123: PHP Fileinfo extension must be installed/enabled to use Intervention Image.for that i enabled it in php.ini file.now iam getting  below error

NotReadableException in AbstractDecoder.php line 302:
Image source not readable.

Any help would be appreciated greatly.

Comment: What's your development platform?

Comment: iam using laravel 5.

Comment: I mean your OS? Are you using Homestead? ...